# Q) crash in openJ9 libcryp due to Memeory Violation in CRYPTO_memcmp

Tags: crash, libcrypto, openj9

**The Context of my question**

My server software is based on

> openjdk version "1.8.0_242"

Nearly ever 2-3 week my server process crashes.
In the Java Dmp file is see that when doing

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
```

there is a memory violation in the libcrypt-1_1 DLL in

```
4XENATIVESTACK               CRYPTO_memcmp+0xe8ef8 (0x00007FFA122A5C18 [libcrypto-1_1-x64+0x185c18])
```

So for me it looks like that CRYPTO_memcmp
forces

> 1XHEXCPCODE    Windows_ExceptionCode: C0000005

**My Question**

Did anybody observe a similar crash with openJ9 or have an idea about the root cause?

Many thanks in advance
Reinhold

Comment: Quick Hint: I have also a different installation ( same software) but libcrypto ois not used. In this case the DLL libeay32.dll is used. But Nevertheless  I get also the memeory violation exception and the crash is in libeay32.dll in the native method NativeCrypto.CBCInit(Native Method).

Comment: BTW:  Both software instanaces are  running on Windows OS

Answer (score 0):

I just think about my implementation which is a server and of cource I am using multitheading.

So I need to double check if libcrypto is Multi-Thread-safe.
If not then this could explain the crash.

But the real question is:  Is the method  myurl.openConnection()
realy thread-safe.
As far as I know it should be thread safe.

I will update with my finding as soon I found something

Comment: I checked : https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API ,  and I found the following note in section Thread Safety --> 
OpenSSL currently is thread-NOT-safe by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've encountered [OpenJ9 issue 8373](https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/8373) which is fixed in the 0.23 release of jdk8u275-b01.

Comment: Great.. many thanks for the hint.. I will give a try to check if the new build fixes the problem.. Mightbe it will take some time before I can confirm it. The server may run few weeks or forever :-)    Cheers  Reinhold